# Generate primary key using different sequence based on a column value

Tags: hibernate, primary-key

I have a table `TABLE1` that has a column C1. The column C1 is a foreign key into table TABLE2. In TABLE1 when a row is inserted I would like to generate the primary key for the row using a sequence based on the value of C1. So if C1 has a value of 1 then I would like to generate primary key from sequence seq1. If C1 has a value of 2 then I would like to generate primary key from sequence seq2 and so on.

I was thinking of using a stored procedure to which I can supply the value in C1. Based on the value in C1 the stored procedure would pick out the correct sequence and get the value from there. For this approach, I believe I will need some sort of hibernate custom id generator. However, I am not sure when inserting a new row in TABLE1 how I can specify the value of C1 to the custom id generator. This value will need to be provided to the stored procedure.

If there is a better alternative to this solution I would be happy to take them up.

Comment: please post minimal reproducible example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am currently in design step against requirements and I don't have any code.

Comment: IMHO a bad idea. A sequence is guaranteed to give unique ids, but if you use 2 sequences, you risk getting same id twice.

Comment: @Lesiak, there are six distinct values in column C1. Each value corresponds to its own sequence range (no overlap).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way of doing this. Instead of using this approach:

> I would like to generate the primary key for the row using a sequence based on the value of C1

I am going to use a surrogate key. For the generation of the business key, identified above, I will use a trigger function upon inserts. The trigger function will inspect the value of C1 and generate the business key based on the value of C1. This is a clean and a simple approach. The only downside being that a Java Developer may find it hard to figure out how the value is generated (I can leave a comment in the code for that).